# Более ей подходящее

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Можно ли говорить **более ей подходящее** вместо **более подходящее для неё** и в каких случаях? Меня смущает, что употребления оборотов **...более ему/ей/мне подходящий/подходящее...** мне найти почти не удалось, в том числе в [Корпусе](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/new/).

Первый вариант, мне он нравится больше:

> Она носила такое платье в прошлом, но потом отказалась: то ли нашла **более ей подходящее**, то ли просто надоело.

Второй:

> Она носила такое платье в прошлом, но потом отказалась: то ли нашла **более подходящее для неё**, то ли просто надоело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обе формы вполне употребительны. Использовать можно как первый оборот, так и второй. В первом случае, вызвавшем у Вас сомнения, ярко выражен причастный оборот, у которого два, как нам кажется, зависимых слова: **ей** и **более**. Первое является обыкновенным дополнением, необходимым для обозначения направленности действия, а второе является **сравнительной степенью наречия меры и степени** и, как Вы, скорее всего, догадались, вполне может использоваться с отглагольными конструкциями. Приведу пример, в большей степени разъясняющие ситуацию:

“Платье подходило ей **больше**“.  Здесь, согласитесь, не возникает сомнений насчёт значения слова "больше" и его уместности. Если сравнивать с предыдущим предложением, где возникло недопонимание, то обнаружим, что оно является инверсией первого и, следовательно, сохраняет значения всех слов.